# Variable synonyms in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch as a search engine for a large number (potentially 1000s) of small text collections. As each of these collections can have collection-specific synonyms, the standard synonym approach in ElasticSearch would have me create one index per collection. However, this leads to a very large number of indices (and therefore, shards), and a high performance risk.

Is there a way to vary synonyms within a single index (for example, by document type or another metadata field), or another way to bring down the number of indices and shards, while keeping the collection-specific synonyms?

Thanks!

Comment: I need more information because I don't understand the question...could you provide an example?

Comment: I have many small collections of texts, which are client-specific. For each client, I would like to use different synonyms. For example: for the collection of client1, I would like to use the synonym mapping bike => bicycle, for the collection of client2, I would not like to use that mapping. Is there a way to do this without putting the collections in different indexes (because that would lead to a very high number of shards)?